# UnicodeDecodeError when import json file

Tags: python, json

I want to open a json file in python and I have the error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 64864: ordinal not in range(128)

my code is quite simple:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import json

with open('birdw3l2.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file)
print(data)
```

Someone can help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code.

```
import json

with open('birdw3l2.json') as data_file:    
    data = json.load(data_file).decode('utf-8')
print(data)
```

Comment: doesn't change a thing :(

Comment: no it's always the same problem. Actually even i don't do print, the error still remains...

Comment: Actually your file contains some special characters. If its a small file, write it again

Comment: or write a program to first remove that special character

Comment: well its a quite large data file

Answer (score 0):

You should specify your encoding format when you load your json file. like this:

```
 data = json.load(data_file, encoding='utf-8')
```

The encoding depends on your file encoding.

Comment: python 3.x no longer has `encoding=`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html